# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Buffer & Module AppRegistry is not registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, react-navigation

I am a newbie on React-native and I am facing some issues. My metro bundler successfully bundles the react native app. after that these errors occur:

1. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Buffer
2. Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
3. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
   and getting a blank white screen on my emulator as shown: [Emulator White Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy5Qy.png)
   here is a picture from Package.json devDependencies: [package.json devDependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2RM3.png)
   here are the dependencies from package.json: [image: package.json dependencies image1] [image: package.json dependencies image2] [image: package.json dependencies image3] [image: package.json dependencies image4]
   any solution will be appreciated.
   thanks in advance

I have tried almost all solutions from different resources but unable to fix them.

Comment: Some pages used the undefined variable: `Buffer`. Please search your project directory to find anything named as 'Buffer' and post it here. If not, it may be called by some dependencies itself. Any file you have edited recently?

Comment: I searched the keyword 'Buffer', but I found no match. another team worked on some components, and their code is working fine on all machines. but i am facing these issues

Comment: Since there is too little information about the error, it is difficult to tell what is wrong. Try comparing `package.json` with another team, maybe some of the dependencies version are different.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, have you managed to fix it?

Comment: No, i am still facing the same problem

Comment: Please share your package.json

Comment: I have added all package.json dependencies and devDependencies in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update the pusher-js version with 7.4.0. It's working fine for me.

`"pusher-js": "^7.4.0",`

Comment: It wasn’t t pusher-js issue.